# c - creating a makefile causes error "expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token"

Tags: c, pointers, makefile, compiler-errors, maze

So I'm creating a maze game program but in order for me to be able to actually start coding, I'm supposed to create a makefile that compiles and links the mazes.c and mazeDisplay.c files into an executable called mazes. The makefile should allow make all and make clean commands to work properly, and I'm also supposed to include something called the -lX11 library in order for the code to link properly.

I've been trying to compile my program and create my makefile for the past 2 days, and I can't get anything to work. My compiler doesn't seem to recognize what a pointer is. I keep getting the error "error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token Graph *computeGraph(char maze[HEIGHT][WIDTH]) {" and I'm starting to get really anxious as my assignment is due soon and I'm unable to even compile the starting program files which I need to start my task because of this makefile issue. Please, any help would be appreciated. I've been losing my mind trying to do a simple task and I just can't figure out what the problem is. Is there something wrong with my makefile instructions?

Makefile:

```
GCC = gcc

all: mazes.o mazeDisplay.o
    $(GCC) -o mazes mazes.o mazeDisplay.o -lX11

mazes.o: mazes.c mazeDisplay.h
    $(GCC) -c mazes.c 

mazeDisplay.o: mazeDisplay.c mazeDisplay.h
    $(GCC) -c mazeDisplay.c

clean:
    rm -f *.o mazes
```

CODE:

mazes.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "graphSet.h"
#include "mazeDisplay.h"




// Compute the graph for the given maze and add it to the given graph set.
Graph *computeGraph(char maze[HEIGHT][WIDTH]) {

  // Create the initially-empty graph

  // Find a starting node, then trace out the maze recursively.  A starting node can be
  // found by searching from top to bottom, left to right, for a non-wall maze location.
  // You MUST NOT hard-code this start location ... it must be determined by your code.

  // To trace out the maze recursively, you will likely want to create a recursive
  // procedure that is called by this one.   It should take parameters to indicate
  // the location in the maze to start tracing from, the maze itself and also the node
  // that led to this node (i.e., the previous one in the tree that led here).  If you
  // start with the root node, then the previous node should be NULL.
  //
  // As you go through the maze, make sure to mark off maze locations that you have
  // visited (perhaps by putting a '2' character at that location) so that you do not
  // go back to that location again and end up with infinite recursion.  So you can
  // stop the recursion when you reach a wall (i.e., a '0' character in the maze) or a
  // '2' character.  A '1' character means that it is a free space that you just arrived
  // at for the first time.   Make sure to check recursively in all directions.  In my
  // solutions (shown on the assignment), I used an ordering of up/down/left/right.  So
  // if you want solutions to look like mine, you should follow that ordering as well.
  //
  // As you traverse the maze, make sure to connect the previous node to the current one.
  // You'll have to check which direction you can from (i.e., x and y values) so that
  // you know whether it is the up/down/left or right pointer to set.

  // You need not do this recursively, but it will lkely be a lot harder to do it non-
  // recursively.

  return NULL; // Remove this line when you write your code
}



// This procedure must clean up graph by removing all nodes in which the previous and
// next nodes have the same x or y value as it.
void cleanUpGraph(Node *n, Node *previousNode) {

}



// This is where it all begins
int main() {
  char mazes[5][HEIGHT][WIDTH] = {
    {"111111111111111111111",
     "100000001000100000001",
     "101111111010111011111",
     "100000000010000010001",
     "101110111111101110111",
     "100010001000000000001",
     "111011111111111110111",
     "101010001000100000001",
     "101110111011101011101",
     "100010000000001010001",
     "101010111011111111111",
     "101000001000100000001",
     "101111111110101111101",
     "100010100000100000101",
     "111110101110101111101",
     "100010001000000010101",
     "101010111111111010111",
     "101010001000000010001",
     "101111111010111011101",
     "100000000010001000001",
     "111111111111111111111"},

    {"111111111111111111111",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "101111111111111111111",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "101111111111111111111",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "111111111111111111101",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "101111111111111111111",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "111111111111111111101",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "101111111111111111111",
     "101111111111111111101",
     "101111111111111111101",
     "101000100010001000101",
     "101010101010101010101",
     "101010101010101010101",
     "101010101010101010101",
     "100010001000100010001",
     "111111111111111111111"},

    {"111111111111111111111",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "101010101010101010101",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "101110111011101110111",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "101111101111101111101",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "101111111001111111101",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "101111111111111111101",
     "100111111111111111001",
     "100011111111111110001",
     "100001111111111100001",
     "100000111111111000001",
     "100000011111110000001",
     "100000001111100000001",
     "100000000111000000001",
     "100000000010000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "111111111111111111111"},

    {"111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111110111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111",
     "111111111111111111111"},

    {"111111111111111111111",
     "111100000000000000001",
     "111000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "100000000000000000001",
     "111111111111111111111"}};

  // Open a display window
  openDisplayWindow();



  // Allocate a GraphSet to store the graphs for each maze
  GraphSet *gSet;

  // Compute the graphs for each maze and add them to a Graph Set
  for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    Graph *g = computeGraph(mazes[i]);

    // Add g to gSet properly
    // ...
  }

  // Show the graphs
  Graph *g; // ... set this to the first graph in gSet ...

  for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    drawMaze(mazes[i]);  // Draw the maze
    // drawGraph(g->rootNode);    // Draw the graph

    getchar();  // Wait for user to press enter

    // cleanUpGraph(g->rootNode, NULL);   // Clean up the graph
    // drawMaze(mazes[i]);
    // drawGraph(g->rootNode);

    // ... get the next graph in the set ...
    // ... INSERT A LINE OF CODE HERE ...

    getchar();  // Wait again for the user to press ENTER before going on to the next maze
  }

  // Free up all allocated memory
  // ...

  // Close the display window
  closeDisplayWindow();
}
```

mazeDisplay.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "graphSet.h"
#include "mazeDisplay.h"

#define SCALE 25

// These are display-related variables
Display *display;
Window   win;
GC       gc;


// Draw the Maze on the window.  
void drawMaze(char grid[WIDTH][HEIGHT]) {
  // First erase background
  XSetForeground(display, gc, 0xFFFFFF);
  XFillRectangle(display, win, gc, 0, 0, 750, 750);
  XFlush(display);

  // Draw the grid maze
  for (int y=0; y<WIDTH; y++) {
    for (int x=0; x<HEIGHT; x++) {
      if (grid[y][x] == '1') 
    XSetForeground(display, gc, 0x333333);
      else
        XSetForeground(display, gc, 0xFFFFFF);
      XFillRectangle(display, win, gc, x*SCALE, y*SCALE, SCALE, SCALE);
    }
  }
  XFlush(display);
}


// Draws an edge with the given color (e.g., 0x0000FF is blue)
// from cell (c1, r1) to cell (c2, r2) of the maze
void drawEdgeWithColor(int c1, int r1, int c2, int r2, int color) {
  XSetForeground(display, gc, color);
  XDrawLine(display, win, gc, c1*SCALE + SCALE/2, r1*SCALE + SCALE/2, c2*SCALE + SCALE/2, r2*SCALE + SCALE/2);
  XFlush(display);
}

// Draws a node with the given color (e.g., 0x0000FF is blue)
// centered at the given cell (c1, r1) of the maze.
void drawNodeWithColor(int c1, int r1, int color) {
  XSetForeground(display, gc, color);
  XFillArc(display, win, gc,
       c1*SCALE-SCALE/4 + SCALE/2,
       r1*SCALE-SCALE/4 + SCALE/2,
       11, 11, 0, 360*64);
  XFlush(display);
}


// Draw a single graph starting at the given root node n.
void drawGraph(Node *n) {
  // Quit recursion if there are no Nodes
  if (n == NULL)
    return;

   // Recursively draw in each direction.  Draw the edges before the recursive call so that
  // vertices are drawn on top of the edges
  if (n->up != NULL) {
    drawEdgeWithColor(n->x, n->y, n->up->x, n->up->y, 0x0000FF);
    drawGraph(n->up);
  }
  if (n->down != NULL) {
    drawEdgeWithColor(n->x, n->y, n->down->x, n->down->y, 0x0000FF);
    drawGraph(n->down);
  }
  if (n->left != NULL) {
    drawEdgeWithColor(n->x, n->y, n->left->x, n->left->y, 0x0000FF);
    drawGraph(n->left);
  }
  if (n->right != NULL) {
    drawEdgeWithColor(n->x, n->y, n->right->x, n->right->y, 0x0000FF);
    drawGraph(n->right);
  }
  drawNodeWithColor(n->x, n->y, 0xFF0000);
}


// Open a display window
int openDisplayWindow() {
  // Opens connection to X server
  display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

  // Create a simple window
  win = XCreateSimpleWindow(display,                 // our connection to server
                RootWindow(display, 0),  // parent window (none in this example)
                0, 0,                // x,y (w.r.t. parent ... ignored here)
                WIDTH*25,HEIGHT*25,      // width, height
                0,                   // border width
                0x000000,                // border color (ignored in this example)
                            0xFFFFFF);               // background color = WHITE

  // Set the name of the window
  XStoreName(display, win, "Maze Displayer");

  // Get the graphics context
  gc = XCreateGC(display, win, 0, NULL);

  // Make it visible
  XMapWindow(display, win);
  XFlush(display);
  usleep(20000);  // sleep for 20 milliseconds.
}


// Close the display window
int closeDisplayWindow() {
  // Clean up and close the window
  XFreeGC(display, gc);
  XUnmapWindow(display, win);
  XDestroyWindow(display, win);
  XCloseDisplay(display);
}
```

mazeDisplay.h:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

#define WIDTH  21
#define HEIGHT 21

// Draw the maze on the window.
extern void drawMaze(char maze[WIDTH][HEIGHT]);

// Draw the graph on the window.
extern void drawGraph(Node *firstNodeOfGraph);

// Open a display window
extern int openDisplayWindow();

// Close a display window
extern int closeDisplayWindow();

// Draws a node with the given color (e.g., 0x0000FF is blue)
// centered at the given cell (c1, r1) of the maze.
extern void drawNodeWithColor(int c1, int r1, int color);

// Draws an edge with the given color (e.g., 0x0000FF is blue)
// from cell (c1, r1) to cell (c2, r2) of the maze
extern void drawEdgeWithColor(int c1, int r1, int c2, int r2, int color);
```

graphSet.h:

```
// This struct represents a single intersection/Node in a maze.  It keeps track
// of the x(i.e., column) and y (i.e. row) of the intersection in the maze
// as well as the Nodes in all 4 directions around it).   NULL is used to
// indicate that no Node is beside it in a particular direction.
typedef struct nd {
  int        x;
  int        y;
  struct nd *up;
  struct nd *down;
  struct nd *left;
  struct nd *right;
} Node;


// This struct represents a single maze graph
typedef struct gr {
  Node       *rootNode;
  struct gr  *nextGraph;
} Graph;


// This struct represents a set of maze graphs
typedef struct {
  Graph  *firstGraph;
  Graph  *lastGraph;
} GraphSet;
```

Log for make:

```
student@COMP2401-F19:~/Desktop/Mazes$ make

gcc -c mazes.c

mazes.c:11:7: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token

 Graph *computeGraph(char maze[HEIGHT][WIDTH]) {


makefile:7: recipe for target 'mazes' failed

make: *** [mazes.o] Error 1
```

Comment: It doesn't look like `make` is the problem.  You can verify that by running the appropriate sequence of compilation commands at the command line, directly.

Comment: You're overcomplicating this.  One of your C files isn't compiling.  Identify which one, and focus on that one file until you get it to compile.  Forget the makefile, forget the other C files.  Once you get it to compile, try the makefile again.  If another C file won't compile, focus on that one.

Comment: You have posted *way* too much code.  Whether for posting a question here or for sorting it out yourself, you should always try to reduce the problem to the smallest one that reproduces the problem.  Often this will make the nature of the problem clear to you, but if it doesn't, the resulting minimal example will likely be clear to one of *us*.

Comment: The only programming file I'm allowed to edit is mazes.c. I honestly didn't see anything wrong with the code, I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: Suggesting you post complete log for 'make'. This will save lot of time

Comment: I posted the error I get when I type 'make' into the terminal. A ^  symbol points at the * symbol infront of computeGraph

Comment: Also, please fix the 'clean' command. It refers to ${OBJ} (not specified). Try 'rm -f *.o mazes' instead

Comment: Not sure there is a problem with the posted question. Can you double check that code matches post ? What version of gcc do you have ?

Comment: The code is the same. I'm not sure what version of gcc this is as it's a school computer, but I assume it's very recent. I guess my issue is less with the makefile and more as to why my mazes.c program won't compile.

Comment: Given the code you've provided there's no explanation for that compiler error.  There must be something else odd happening here.  As mentioned above this has _nothing_ to do with your makefile.  I recommend you run the compiler directly from the prompt, with: `gcc -c mazes.c`  Does it print this same error?  I assume so.  If so I then recommend you run `gcc -E -dD -o mazes.i mazes.c` and examine the output file `mazes.i`.  You'll need to figure out why `Graph` is apparently being turned into some other token.

Comment: I opened mazes.i and it's a really long list of output that I can't comprehend. Is there something I should be looking for?

Comment: I know it looks confusing.  Basically this is the contents of that source file after all the headers (`#include ...`) have been included.  This is the text the compiler is seeing.  As I mentioned, you need to look for the definition of `Graph` so search the file for `Graph` and see where it is used.

Comment: Alternatively if you post the output somewhere such as pastebin and add a link to it I'll take a look at it.

Comment: The output is here: https://pastebin.com/cVKP05CN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your pastebin your files that are being compiled are corrupted and not the same as the ones you've show us here.

According to the pastebin output, the `mazeDisplay.h` file contains this text:

```
extern void drawMaze(char maze[21][21]);

extern void drawGraph(Node *firstNodeOfGraph);

extern int openDisplayWindow();

extern int closeDisplayWindow();

extern void drawNodeWithColor(int c1, int r1, int color);

extern void drawEdgeWithColor(int c1, int r1, int
```

(comments etc. are elided by the preprocessor).  Note how this file ends right in the middle of the function declaration for `drawEdgeWithColor()`.

This is why you're seeing the syntax error you get: because the end of this last line in the `mazeDisplay.h` file is missing.

All I can suggest is that when you copied these files over to your virtual machine, you somehow didn't copy the entire file but missed the last few characters.

It's usually better to use something like `scp` to copy files.  But another important lesson here is that when asking for help be sure to provide the actual files you're working with, cut and pasted from the system where you're compiling them, rather than publishing other files you think are the same... they  might not be.  People cannot help you if the information given to them is not accurate.

In addition to that there's also something odd in your `mazes.c` file; it looks like you tried to insert the contents of the `graphSet.h` file directly into the `mazes.c` file; you don't need to do that and you should definitely not include both of them.

Comment: jesus, thank you so much for being so patient and doing all that work sir, i really appreciate it!! i can't believe this all came from a copy error. eitherway, i'm so thankful, i'll be sure to follow your advice for any future posts!!

Answer (score 0):

There is something strange about the `makefile`:

The rule:

```
all: mazes.o mazeDisplay.o
    $(GCC) -o mazes maze.o mazeDisplay.o -lX11
```

Should refer to `mazes.o` and not `maze.o`. Once I've fix that project compiles for me (Mint 19/Gcc 7.4). Running it display the maze.

Comment: hey, I changed maze.o to mazes.o. The last 2 lines of the make log message changed a bit (which I updated on the post), but I'm still getting the “expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token” error. I'm using VM VirtualBox. I'm not even sure if the makefile is causing the error. mazes.c won't compile because of the * symbol, but I don't see anything wrong with the code I was given.